# Handling permissions and data in a distributed python script

Tags: python, permissions, chmod, pypi

I'm trying to distribute a python script through Pypi. This script takes input from a user and stores it in a text file. However, because the script is creating/writing to a text file, it requires a "sudo" every time it runs. I.e.:

```
$ my_script
Permission error
$ sudo my_script
Success
```

I've run into this problem while working on another script and solved it by chmod-ing a newly created file. This way, sudo was required only once to create a file with lowered permissions (that could be written to w/o extra privileges). However, I can't believe that this is the best answer to such a problem— requiring users to give privileges to a no-name script seems awfully suspicious. Is there really not a cleaner way to handle recording data when distributing through Pypi?

Comment: Why not write the text into a file the user has permission? In `$HOME`, or in `~/.cache/` or such?…

Comment: I was wondering about writing my file where the user had permission but I (embarrassingly) did not think of the home directory! Thanks!